# Characterizing complex number quadratic on magnitude.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z$ be a complex number such that
$$z^2-(a+bi)z+1 = 0$$
for real numbers $a,b.$ Given that the magnitude of $z$ is at least $2$ and at most $4$, find all possible values of $a,b.$

---

By quadratic formula, we have solutions
$$z=\frac{-(a+bi) \pm \sqrt{(a+bi)^2 - 4}}{2}.$$
I'm trying to separate it into complex and real parts, but the square root is difficult to deal with. Otherwise, I can just use the expressions for $a,b$ and set up inequalities.

Comment: Hint: write it as $a+bi=z+\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: I have tried that, but how to use? I thought quadratic was more useful

Comment: I also tried complex plane interpretation

Comment: Then $|a+bi|^2=\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)\left(\bar z+\frac{1}{\bar z}\right)=|z|^2+\frac{1}{|z|^2}+2 \Re\frac{z}{\bar z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @dxiv's suggestion in the comment section to write $a+bi=z+\frac 1z$, since you need a little more help, I shall give you another hint:
For complex numbers $z_1, z_2$, the following is true:
$$||z_1|-|z_2||\leq |z_1+z_2|\leq |z_1|+|z_2|$$
Can you do it now?

Comment: I found that $$||z|-\frac{1}{|z|}| \le \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \le |z| + \frac{1}{|z|}.$$ I think this means that $|a+bi|$ must be at least $2-\frac{1}{2} = 1.5$ and at most $4+\frac{1}{4} = 4.25.$ Does this mean the region of $a+bi$ is the "donut" containing all points $p$ such that $1.5 \le |p| \le 4.25$?

Comment: Yes that's true

Comment: So that should be the final answer, no exceptions? @Ritam_Dasgupta

Comment: No exceptions, and you can check that yourself. Draw the graph of $x+\frac1x$ and $x-\frac 1x$ in the interval $[2,4]$. Here $x$ represents $|z|$. Notice that in this interval, for a particular $x$, the points lying on the straight vertical line which are greater than $x-\frac 1x$ but more than $x+\frac 1x$ would be acceptable. You will see that all points in your mentioned interval fall in this category.

Comment: @WWesEEE The bounds are correct, but you still need to show that they are tight bounds. For that, it's enough to find actual values of $z$ such that $|a+bi|=3/2$ and $|a+bi|=17/4$.

Comment: Unless i'm missing something, I can't find a $z$ such that $2\le |z| \le 4$ that satisfy those.

Comment: Also, I had a follow up question: If we plot all the points $z+\frac{1}{z}$ on the complex plane such that $2 \le |z| \le 4$ what is it's area?

Comment: @WWesEEE For the bounds to be attained the inequalities must become actual equalities. Think at when the triangle inequality becomes an equality (hint: degenerate triangles). Then find the $z$ values to make that happen.

Comment: @dxiv  Sorry for bothering you; I tried finding the area of all $z+\frac{1}{z}$ on the complex plane, and Ritam_Dasgupta said that it should be the donut containing all complex $p$ such that $1.5 \le |p| \le 4.25.$ This results in $253\pi/16$. However, I am told this is wrong?

Comment: @WWesEEE This is a rather different question than originally asked. What's proved so far is that the image of $z+ \frac{1}{z}$ is included in the circular ring between the two circles $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\frac{3}{2}, \frac{17}{4}$, but *not* that it's equal to it. In fact, it's not. The image of a circle $|z|=r \in [2,4]$ is an ellipse in the $(a,b)$ plane, see [How to prove f(z)=z+1/z maps circles with r≠1 onto ellipses](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163037/) for example. So the image of the ring $2 \le |z| \le 4$ is the region between two such ellipses.